# bootsrtap modal is not showing up

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

I am trying to implement a code to open a bootstrap modal after clicking on a button. but for a reason the modal is not showing up. here is my code

```
 <button type="button" id="asd" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#exampleModalCenter" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block"><b> לתשלום <i class="fas fa-credit-card"></i></b></button>

                    <!-- Modal -->
                    <div class="modal fade rtl text-left" id="exampleModalCenter" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalCenterTitle" aria-hidden="true">
                        <div class="modal-dialog modal-dialog-centered" role="document">
                            <div class="modal-content">
                                <div class="modal-header">
                                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLongTitle">אישור הזמנה</h5>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-body">
                                    <div class="container">
                                        <p class="text-center text-muted">הזמנה בס"כ:
                                            ₪<script>
                                                document.write(<?php cart_total(); ?>);
                                            </script>
                                        </p>
                                    </div>
                                    <button id="paySubmission" type="submit" name="checkout" class="btn btn-success btn-lg btn-block" ><b> מאשר הזמנה </b></button>
                                </div>
                                <div class="modal-footer">
                                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">סגור</button>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

I don't know why the modal is not showing up after the click... someone can help?

Comment: Please create [mcve]

Comment: try to use elementinspector to check what is going on, i guess you have to put the modal on the very bottom before closing body tag. So it might be open but it doesnt show due to parents styles

Comment: I hope you know that if `<script>
                                                document.write(<?php cart_total(); ?>);
                                            </script>` executes, it is going to destroy the entire page...

Comment: Seems to work http://jsfiddle.net/wo0x86dt/

Comment: Why it is going to destroy the entire page?

Comment: @TJ only if it was called after the initial page load though, right? I don’t see an indication here, that that was the case. Still looks like an utterly pointless construct in this place though.

Comment: Ok I forgot the specifics of it, let's just say it's terrible practice and can have unexpected consequences :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that for some reason the loader.php file was not loaded properly. and in that file all bootstrap .js files were loaded from.

So I fixed the problem which prevented loader.php file to load, and the problem has been fixed.

Thank you